# How to display the survey results created with the Webform module?

Tags: webforms

Does anybody know how to display the survey results created with the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module?

I have created a survey using the grid field and it works great. I want to be able to display the accumulated results (using my CSS styling) on the same page the survey question appears. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create **charts** from the survey results of the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module, there are 2 alternatives to pick from:

- **[Webform Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_charts)** (used in about 400 sites), to display Webform results in a graphical manner using a charting library.
- **[Webform Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_chart)** (used in about 220 sites), which integrates with the "Analysis" tab of a Webform (created with the Webform module) to provide charts for each individual component's analytical data.

The Drupal 7 version of both modules, requires the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module (dependency).